# Which one to select "Top Down" or "Bottom Up" approach in DP?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, topdown, bottom-up

Bottom up technique looks little bit easier when it comes to solve a question(my view), but whether it can be used everywhere where we are using Top Down approach or is there any specific instance when we can or we should use bottom up technique ?